# TurfJS get bbox given two Points

Tags: leaflet, geojson, turfjs

I'm trying to move a client side method on the backend:

The client side method is using TurfJS and Leaflet to perform some operations. The only problem is that server side (nodejs) window is not available, hence I cannot use Leaflet.

I'm looking for a way to transform this piece of code in the vanilla Turf equivalent:

```js
    const pointA = turf.point([originCoords.lng, originCoords.lat]);
    const pointB = turf.destination.default(pointA, 50, 45, { units: 'kilometers' });

    // here I'm using leaflet to get a BBox
    const latLngBounds = L.latLngBounds(
        L.latLng(pointA.geometry.coordinates[1],
            pointA.geometry.coordinates[0]),
        L.latLng(pointB.geometry.coordinates[1], pointB.geometry.coordinates[0]),
    );

    // using that BBox I then create the rectangle, again with leaflet
    tile = L.rectangle(latLngBounds);
```

I'm still newbie with this whole GeoJSON thing, and maybe I'm missing something, can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code that uses Turf.JS only.

```
var turf = require('@turf/turf');
var pointA = turf.point([-75.343, 39.984]);
var pointB = turf.destination(pointA, 50, 45, { units: 'kilometers' });
//create a bbox that extends to include all the features
var bbx = turf.bbox(turf.featureCollection([pointA, pointB]));
var pgn = turf.bboxPolygon(bbx);  //convert it to Polygon feature
console.log(JSON.stringify(pgn)); //output to console
```

The output:

```
{"type":"Feature","properties":{},
    "geometry":{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[[
        [-75.343,39.984],
        [-74.92609,39.984],
        [-74.92609,40.3012],
        [-75.343,40.3012],
        [-75.343,39.984]]]
    }
}
```

Edit 1

Add ability to run the code:

```js
//var turf = require('@turf/turf');
var pointA = turf.point([-75.343, 39.984]);
var pointB = turf.destination(pointA, 50, 45, { units: 'kilometers' });
//create a bbox that extends to include all the features
var bbx = turf.bbox(turf.featureCollection([pointA, pointB]));
var pgn = turf.bboxPolygon(bbx);  //convert it to Polygon feature
console.log(JSON.stringify(pgn)); //output to console
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Turf.js/5.1.5/turf.min.js"></script>
```